# Why doesn't memory consumed by balloon driver not show up in top?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, memory-usage

On an overallocated ESX host, guest is allocated 80GB RAM. The balloon driver kicked in at some point, and is consuming quite a bit of memory.

```
# vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon
52381 MB
```

Now guest-os thinks 77G of 80G is in use.

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         80586      77570       3015       1220        101       1800
```

However, why do I not see this when I run top (sorted by memory)? My top process is only using 2GB of RAM. Where  does the guest OS think the ~50GB of memory vanished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ballooning uses a kernel module (installed as part of VMware Tools) to allocate the memory in the guest. So, it is the Linux kernel that consumes the memory, but not one of the regular processes that top would show.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. So, as a naive guest-os user, is there a way for me to detect ballooning? (not using vmware-toolbox commands that is)

Comment: Are any of these comments appropriate? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97265

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I looked at the slabtop tool and the information in /proc/meminfo, but was not really able to "see" the memory consumption of ballooning in there.

Comment: Yeah, me neither.  Even with https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/vm/page-types.c, I was disappointed just to see an ever increasing number of pages with zero flags.  Zero, what could that mean, except leaked?